A proof that 4 ≥ ∞ when using the Quantum One-Time Pad
A cryptographic scheme using a $n$-bit key to hide a $m$-bit plaintext is said to be perfectly secret when, without this key, we cannot get any information about the plaintext from the ciphertext. Therefore, from the ciphertext, we cannot rule out any $m$-bit plaintext. That is, every $m$-bit plaintext could have caused this ciphertext. Therefore, if we were to try to decipher using brute-force (that is, by trying to decipher using every possible $n$-bit key), we would obtain every $m$-bit plaintext (possibly with redundancies).
A density matrix is a complex square matrix that represents a quantum system. There are infinitely many $2 \times 2$ density matrices.
Let $\rho$ be a $2 \times 2$ density matrix, and let $(a, b) \in \{0, 1\}^2$. By applying the Quantum One-Time Pad on $\rho$ using the keys $a$ and $b$, we obtain a new density matrix $\sigma = X^aZ^b\rho Z^bX^a$. The Quantum One-Time Pad ensures perfect secrecy. That is, if we were to try to decipher $\sigma$ using brute-force (that is, by trying to apply $X^uZ^v\sigma Z^vX^u$ for every $(u, v) \in \{0, 1\}^2$), we would end up finding every $2 \times 2$ density matrices from the remark above. Since there are only four pairs of $(u, v) \in \{0, 1\}^2$, then by brute-forcing, we would obtain only four (not necessarily distinct) $2 \times 2$ density matrices.
Therefore, there are at most four $2 \times 2$ density matrices, but there are also infinitely many. As such, $4 \geq +\infty$.
Can you find the mistake? Because I can't.

Welcome to QCSE.  Are you thinking that you can generate all possible $2\times 2$ density matrices, starting from a given matrix $\rho$, by choosing a twirl at random? Have you started by picking a two $2\times 2$ density matrices $\rho$ and $\sigma$ at random, and then randomly applying the four twirls to $\rho$ to see if you can ever get to $\sigma$ or vice-versa?

@MarkSpinelli No, I don't think so. And this is exactly the problem. If we could do so, it would mean there are only four density matrices. However, there are infinitely many of them. But, if we can't do so, then it means the Quantum One-Time Pad doesn't provide perfect secrecy. But the Quantum One-Time Pad indeed provides perfect secrecy. So, I'm quite confused.

I think your problem is that you haven't made precise what "perfect secrecy" is. Try to write down a formal mathematical definition.

The Quantum One-Time Pad is information-theoretically secure in the same manner as the (classical) One-Time Pad or Vigenère cipher is.  I think your interpretation of "perfect secrecy" is overplayed or overbroad - it doesn't imply that we could encrypt any density matrix $\rho$ into every possible one of the uncountably infinite, or even countably infinite, density matrices $\sigma$.  Each such density matrix itself will be drawn from some prior.
For example when Alice sends qubits to Bob in the BB84 protocol, she applies a twirl of her choosing, uniformly at random to, say, $|0\rangle$.  Thus if Eve intercepts Alice's qubit it's not true that Eve doesn't know anything about the intercepted qubit; she knows it is promised to be one of $\big\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle,|+\rangle,|-\rangle\big\}$.
Any qubit intercepted by Eve will not be drawn from an $\infty$ number of density matrices; it will only be drawn from one of the four possible BB84 states; nonetheless it is still information-theoretically impossible for Eve to know which of the four BB84 states she has intercepted.  Likewise, any single (classical) bit  that's been encrypted with the Vigenère cipher and that Eve intercepts intercepts won't be one of an $\infty$ number of bits; it will either be $0$ or $1$.

It is not relevant to the main point, but while the classical one-time pad is information-theoretically secure, the Vigenère cipher is not, unless the message happens to be as short as the key (in which case it reduces to the one-time pad).

Let us define information-theoretically-secure encryption as follows: given any fixed plaintext, the distribution of ciphertext over uniform random keys is statistically indistinguishable from uniform.
In classical cryptography, this implies that given any ciphertext-plaintext pair, there exists a key that decrypts the given ciphertext to the given plaintext. However, this implication does not hold in quantum cryptography.
This is because, in classical cryptography, the adversary is assumed to have perfect knowledge of the ciphertext. If then there was a plaintext that a given ciphertext could not be decrypted to, then knowing the ciphertext gives a computationally-unbounded adversary some knowledge about the plaintext. However, in quantum cryptography the adversary is not assumed to know the description of the ciphertext state.
Why then is the QOTP information-theoretically-secure? First, we ought to define what it means for quantum states to be "uniformly-distributed". Given an ensemble of quantum states $\left| \psi_1 \right>, \ldots, \left| \psi_n \right>$ with corresponding probabilities $ p_1, \ldots, p_n $, we describe their distribution with the mixed state $ \sum_{i=1}^n p_i \left| \psi_i \right> \left< \psi_i \right| $. A uniformly-random distribution over all possible quantum states is described by the fully-mixed state, which for an $m$-qubit system is given by $\frac{1}{2^m} I$ (where $I$ is the $(2^m \times 2^m)$-dimensional identity matrix).
If you compute $ \frac{1}{4} \sum_{a, b \in \{0, 1\}} X^u Z^v \sigma Z^v X^u$ for any arbitrary pure state density matrix $ \sigma $, you will find that it is the fully-mixed state $\frac{1}{2} I$. Hence, although not every possible QOTP ciphertext can be decrypted to any possible QOTP plaintext, the ciphertext still does not reveal any information on the plaintext because it is statistically indistinguishable from a quantum state chosen uniformly at random from the universe of quantum states. Incidentally, this shows that a finitely-sized ensemble of quantum states can be indistinguishable from an infinitely-sized one.
Note that this no longer holds if the adversary receives multiple copies of the ciphertext. When using QOTP, it is not safe to re-send a previously-sent ciphertext.
In summary: for a quantum encryption scheme to be information-theoretically-secure, it does not have to hold that a given ciphertext must be decryptable to any given plaintext.
This answer is a little less formal and more wordy than I would have liked, but I hope that it is still somewhat useful in the context of the question given.

What do you mean in your paragraph beginning “If you compute…”?

@MarkSpinelli That the mixed-state density matrix representing the distribution of QOTP ciphertexts (over uniformly-distributed keys) for any given pure state quantum plaintext is the fully-mixed state.
Thus, the ciphertext state is statistically indistinguishable from a state drawn at random from the universe of all $2 \times 2$ states.
This part could admittedly do with a little more rigour, since properly you can't define a uniform distribution over an infinite sample space.
